# Twilio - Super Sim - Incoming SMS to Sim card

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api, super

I am trying to achieve 2 way messaging with a super sim. I have been able to successfully configure sms received on my virtual Twilio number to be delivered to my sim by Http post (with authentication).

I would like to find a way to send an SMS from the sim and receive the SMS at a specific phone number.  I've tried several flows without any success. I was able to get this working on Make.com and retrieve the data structure of the webhook but I still cant get this working on Twilio.

Thank you for the reply.

The sim is in an iot device and I am able to achieve 2 way communication utilizing webhooks with make.com. What I would like to achieve is to utilize a virtual number with Twilio to be the associated number for the iot device.

I have successfully received incoming "SMS" messages (commands) to the iot device, using a studio flow. When an sms is received via my virtual number number on twilio, the studio flow fires an https Post with the appropriate payload, populated from the received webhook from the virtual number., in turn receiving the "SMS" on the iot device.

Now I would like to create a flow or something similar on Twilio, that would generate a Twilio webhook that would listen for SMS commands (replies) "sent from" my appropriate Super Sim.

On Make.com I am able to generate the webhook and analyze the data structure, successfully receiving the payload of the webhook, from my Sim Fleet. I would like to utilize only Twilio for the webhooks, if possible. Do you have any more suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio Super Sim is not intended for use in a phone and does not support voice or regular SMS.

The Super Sim does support [sending](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/smscommand-resource#sms-commands-from-sim-mobile-originated) and [receiving command (machine to machine, M2M) messages over SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/smscommand-resource#sms-commands-to-sim-mobile-terminated) which can be used to send instructions to the device or receive data from a device. In this case the sim card can send messages to the number `000` and those messages will be received by Twilio and turned into a webhook request.

There is some documentation for [how to send command messages from the Super Sim from a Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/get-started-with-super-sim-sms-commands) or [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/get-started-with-super-sim-and-the-raspberry-pi-pico) and an in depth article on [AT Commands](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/introduction-at-commands) that you can use to control the Sim.